# Can an out of bounds player down a football in the field of play?

Tags: rules, american-football

In Steelers/Ravens game on Jan 6, 2024, the Steelers kick returner (Godwin Igwebuike) intentionally went out of bounds and touched a kickoff while lying across the sideline, being both in bounds and out of bounds therefore having not re-established himself in the field of play.

Was this the correct call by the officials?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a reasonably well known point in the rules (at least if you watch "NFL IQ 100 plays" on YouTube or similar), perhaps most famously when [Ty Montgomery did it for the Packers in 2016](https://www.sbnation.com/2016/9/25/13049606/packers-kick-return-ty-montgomery-randall-cobb).